# Built in functions available in opencv2 python to find distance between to images

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy, cross-correlation

I want a **faster Normalized cross correlation** using which i can compute similarity between two images. I want to know whether there is any built in functions which can find correlation between two images other than **scipy.signal.correlate2d() and matplotlib xcorr()**. If these two functions are working can anyone show me an example to find correlation between two images.

```
path1='D:/image/cat1.jpg'
path2='D:/image/cat2.jpg'
corrCoefft = computeCorrelationCoefft(path1,path2)
```

Comment: Why don't you like scipy.signal.correlate2d?  If speed is the issue, did you try it with fft=True?  If you don't want this, you can easily write your own using the FFT, which is generally the fastest way (computationally).  Here's a 1D example I wrote awhile ago, and 2D is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199972/cython-and-numpy-speed/1228914#1228914  (Note, though, the FFT assumes periodic boundary conditions, so you have to deal with that.)

Comment: Also, btw, OpenCV (ie, cv2) does cross-correlation of various types with the function `matchTemplate`, with, eg, `CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED`.  If none of these work, you need to be very specific about why not, and what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: @tom10 -Thank you for your guidance, and i have edited the code and provided the snippet of code for others to try out various distance metrics for image similarity matching

Comment: @tom10- I am not able to mark this question as answered as ur solution has already yielded me result. and i have also edited my code to help others.

Comment: if you don't mind, let's turn this into a proper SO question/answer so it will be more useful to others.  I've added an answer using your code, so maybe you could accept this and then edit your question so it doesn't contain the answer.  (If you'd rather just post the answer yourself, that's fine too, and you can accept that instead and I'll delete mine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV does normalized cross-correlations using the function [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html), with, eg, `CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED`.

@Jonas suggested the following code to use this and compare the different methods

```
img = cv2.imread(path1)
template = cv2.imread(path2)
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR','cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED',     'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for i in range(len(methods)):
    result[i] = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,methods[i])
    print ("Method {}  : Result{}") .format(method[i],result[i])
```

Comment: @tom10-I just wanted beginners to know that this method had a flaw , Thanks for your answer and support .